# kustomize edit set image doesn't work with kustomize multibases and common base

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I am using this [example](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/examples/multibases/README.md):

```
├── base
│   ├── kustomization.yaml
│   └── pod.yaml
├── dev
│   └── kustomization.yaml
├── kustomization.yaml
├── production
│   └── kustomization.yaml
└── staging
    └── kustomization.yaml
```

and in `kustomization.yaml` file in root:

```
resources:
- ./dev
- ./staging
- ./production
```

I also have the image transformer code in `dev, staging, production` kustomization.yaml:

```
images:
- name: my-app
  newName: gcr.io/my-platform/my-app
```

To build a single deployment manifest, I use:

```
(cd dev && kustomize edit set image my-app=gcr.io/my-platform/my-app:0.0.2 && kustomize build .)
```

which simply works!

to build deployment manifest for all overlays (dev, staging, production), I use:

```
(kustomize edit set image my-app=gcr.io/my-platform/my-app:0.0.2 && kustomize build .)
```

which uses the `kustomization.yaml` in root which contains all resources(dev, staging, production).

It does work and the final build is printed on console but without the image tag.

It seems like the `kusotmize edit set image` only updates the `kustomizaion.yaml` of the current dir.

Is there anything which can be done to handle this scenario in an easy and efficient way so the final output contains image tag as well for all deployments?

[To test please use this repo](https://github.com/D-GC/kustomize-multibase)

Comment: Are you sure you are issuing this command exactly the same as in your question? I recreated the environment from above example, issued your command, and the build is printed **with** image tag. Also, is your image name in `base/pod.yaml` "image-name"?

Comment: Hi @p10l, thank you for having a look and testing it. Please check this [repo](https://github.com/D-GC/kustomize-multibase). I have also added the output of commands in Readme

Comment: And name of image was `image-name` in pod.yaml, but in the example repo I have changed it to `my-app` and updated the commands as well

Comment: Is there a reason why you are issuing commands in subshell (inside `()`)?

Comment: so cd is temporary

Comment: So far to me it seems like using `sed -i "s/image: my-app/image: gcr.io\/my-platform\/my-app:0.0.2" base/deployment.yaml` command before executing `kustomize build` is an easy compromised solution until I find a better or kustomize way of doing it.

Comment: @Arian What you do is to change the image name manually and your `overlay/kustomization.yaml` doesn't work. Please refer to my answer below to understand what happens and why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It took some time to realise what happens here. I'll explain step by step what happens and how it should work.

### What happens

Firstly I re-created the same structure:

```
$ tree
.
├── base
│   ├── kustomization.yaml
│   └── pod.yaml
├── dev
│   └── kustomization.yaml
├── kustomization.yaml
└── staging
    └── kustomization.yaml
```

When you run this command for single deployment:

```
(cd dev && kustomize edit set image my-app=gcr.io/my-platform/my-app:0.0.2 && kustomize build .)
```

you change working directory to `dev`, manually override image from `gcr.io/my-platform/my-app` and adding tag `0.0.2` and then render the deployment.

The thing is previously added `transformer code` gets overridden by the command above. You can remove `transformer code`, run the command above and get the same result. And after running the command you will find out that your `dev/kustomization.yaml` will look like:

```
resources:
- ./../base
namePrefix: dev-
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
images:
- name: my-app
  newName: gcr.io/my-platform/my-app
  newTag: 0.0.2
```

**Then** what happens when you run this command from main directory:

```
(kustomize edit set image my-app=gcr.io/my-platform/my-app:0.0.2 && kustomize build .)
```

`kustomize` firstly goes to overlays and do `transformation code` which is located in `overlays/kustomization.yaml`. When this part is finished, image name is **not** `my-app`, but `gcr.io/my-platform/my-app`.

At this point `kustomize edit` command tries to find image with name `my-app` and can't do so and therefore does NOT apply the `tag`.

### What to do

You need to use transformed image name if you run `kustomize edit` in main working directory:

```
$ kustomize edit set image gcr.io/my-platform/my-app=*:0.0.4 && kustomize build .

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    app: my-app
  name: dev-myapp-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - image: gcr.io/my-platform/my-app:0.0.4
    name: my-app
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    app: my-app
  name: stag-myapp-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - image: gcr.io/my-platform/my-app:0.0.4
    name: my-app
```

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor :) this works `edit set image gcr.io/my-platform/my-app=*:0.0.4`

Comment: @moonkotte Thank you so much for taking your time and explaining it so well with a solution :)